# Is it possible to communicate without a router by connecting the device and the smartphone via Wi-Fi?

Tags: android

To connect a device (ex. air purifier) ​​made with a Wi-Fi chip to a phone and control it from the outside
I was told that there should be three devices: a device (Wi-Fi chip internal IP), a router (Wi-Fi), and a smartphone.
Is it possible to think of the device itself as a router without a router and control it from the outside by connecting to a smartphone and Wi-Fi?

Video while searching YouTube (video of making a toy car with a Wi-Fi chip (Arduino), finding out the IP address, and controlling it by entering the IP with the Android app)
Is it controlled from the outside through bidirectional communication (device sensor value->smartphone and smartphone->device power on/off)?

Samsung or Kakao air purifiers are said to require a router.
I was wondering if it is possible to connect directly and send/receive data using only an air purifier and two smartphones.

Comment: If the smartphone near the device is being used as a mobile hotspot (internet sharing) then the smartphone can provide internet connectivity for the device. Your other smartphone should then be able to connect to the device remotely, as the device is now connected to the internet.

Comment: @CSchwarz. Only the first part comes true. But a second mobile device cannot connect to the first mobile device as mobile providers block incoming connections. Sorry. Running servers on an Android device only makes sense using wifi.

Comment: @blackapps If the device (e.g. air purifier) communicates through a 3rd party server then it will most likely be fine. If you are trying to remote into a device directly then yes I agree that it will possibly be blocked by the mobile provider.

Comment: @CSchwarz So the device itself can't be used like a router and can't be controlled externally without a router?

Comment: @YeonJiJu If you want to connect directly to an internal device via an IPv4 address remotely then it depends on the capabilities of the hotspot and if the mobile network provider is blocking inbound traffic. e.g. can your mobile hotspot forward external traffic to the internal device? But via IPv6 it is easier, you may be able to connect directly to the device without forwarding by typing the ipv6 address and port in remotely (if firewall isn't blocking it). But note many smart devices allow remote control through web portals on 3rd party servers, if that is the case it is most likely fine.